# Can update set field replace multiple files

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, set, field

I am learning mysql and i have this

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES set name = replace(name, 'ANTONIO', 'TONIO');
```

I want to test if it can replace multiple persons name, thanks a lot?

Comment: This will replace the `name` field, for all entries in `employees`, by replacing any substring of `Antonio` with just `Tonio`. For entries where name is like `JustCarty`, no change will take place.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. REPLACE() can only replace one fixed string with another fixed string.

In general, SQL has pretty mediocre string-manipulation functions. If you want to do a lot of replacements, then create a mapping table and load the old name and new name:

```
CREATE TABLE NameMapping (
 old_name VARCHAR(64), 
 new_name VARCHAR(64), 
 PRIMARY KEY (old_name)
);
INSERT INTO NameMapping (old_name, new_names) VALUES 
 ('ANTONIO', 'TONIO'),
 ...more pairs...
```

Then you can do a multi-table update to apply them all at once:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES JOIN NameMapping ON EMPLOYEES.name = NameMapping.old_name
SET EMPLOYEES.name = NameMapping.new_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is absolutely correct if you want to replace `ANTONIO` in any name with `TONIO`

DB-FIDDLE :

```
 CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50));
 INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES(1,'ANTONIO');
 INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES(2,'ANTONIO BENDERAS');
 INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES(3,'TONY ANTONIO');
```

Your update Query:

```
 UPDATE EMPLOYEES set name = replace(name, 'ANTONIO', 'TONIO');
```

Select query:

```
 SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Output:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TONIO |
| 2 | TONIO BENDERAS |
| 3 | TONY TONIO |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ca11eaf87dcd915a22a7813c34d28ec)*